# Is it possible to install new module without ftp in drupal 6?

Tags: 6, installation

I don't have the cpanel password of my hosting, I want to install new module through website. It's easy in D7, how can I do it in D6.

Note: if you suggest any module, I can't install that too through ftp and I don't know drush too.

Comment: If the module directory is writeable from the user account used to run the web server, you can create a node whose body uses the PHP filter.

Comment: @kiamlaluno yaa it's writable, how should I do that using php?

Comment: A place to start looking might be the update_manager_batch_project_get() function in Drupal 7. You could replicate the parts of that system you need and I'm sure you could simplify it greatly as a one off script for your own use. You could potentially run it from the execute php page the devel module provides (devel/php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all directories are writable, you should be able to enable PHP module, create a node with PHP filter, and in that node use:

```
file_put_contents ( 'path_to_modules/mymodule/mymodule.info', 'name = example
description = Demonstrates how to write info file.
core = 6.x');
```

The same for module file.

Preferably do that with rudimentary module that will allow you to upload and extract zip / tar.gz module files as provided by Drupal.org, and then remove PHP filtered node and disable PHP module.